Installing TALYS (nuclear reaction code) in Windows
Sure, here's the corrected text with improved grammar and clarity:
Hello,
I'm trying to install TALYS 2.0, a nuclear reaction code, on Windows 11. I have Fortran installed via MinGW.
First, I changed the paths in the path_change file to make them compatible with Windows. Then, I navigated to the talys/source directory and ran make in the terminal. After that, I changed the directory to the bin folder, where talys.exe was created, and ran ./talys.exe in the terminal.
However, nothing happens after running ./talys.exe. I can type anything in the terminal, but the command prompt does not start with the path, and I have to reset the terminal because it becomes useless. I also tried running it with a sample file using ./talys.exe sample, but the result is the same.
I have tried using the windows terminal, the one from Visual Studio Code, and MSYS2, all with the same result.
I would appreciate any help with this.
